# Есть ли такая почта уже в таблице mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, авторизация, email, проверка

Необходимо добавить в код условие. Если такая почта уже есть в таблице, то выдать ошибку "E-Mail адрес занят"

Как часть кода с условиями выглядит сейчас:

```
if (empty($login)){ api::result('Вы не ввели никнейм!');}
    if (empty($email)){ api::result('Вы не ввели E-mail');}
    if (empty($password)){ api::result('Вы не ввели пароль!');}
    if (empty($repeat)){ api::result('Вы не ввели повторно пароль!');}
    if (empty($sex)){ api::result('Вы не указали пол!');}
```

Вот таким row'ом обозначается почта у меня если что.

```
$rows["email"]
```

Comment: а что это за фреймворк или т.п. ?

Comment: В файлах сайта упоминаний о framework не нашел

Answer (score 1):

Тогда Пробуйте так:

```
db::q('SELECT * FROM 'таблица' where 'email' = "'.$_POST['email'].'"'); 
if (db::n() == 1) {
    api::result('E-mail уже занят!');
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Это условие не выполняться. Возможно подобное условие "есть ли такое имя в бд" чем-то поможет с ответом для меня! Вот оно   db::q('SELECT * FROM '.$rows['table'].' where '.$rows['login'].' = "'.$login.'" LIMIT 1');
  if(db::n() == 1){   
    api::result('Аккаунт с таким именем уже существует!');

Comment: Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Вот целиком файл http://rgho.st/829q7fxVK

Comment: @CoffeeinTime, к слову, в любом случае никогда не вклеивайте вручную email в запрос. Если Вы скинете полностью содержимое `db` класса (предварительно, разумеется, убрав оттуда адреса и пароли), Вам даже подскажут, как заменить это дело на PDO или mysqli. Скорее всего даже там уже всё это есть, и тогда Вам подскажут как этим правильно пользоваться. Про PDO можете прочитать [тут](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo), там же справа есть ссылки на связанные статьи.